# Spring - Allow only specific parameters in the query string otherwise throw an error

Tags: java, spring

We have a requirement where we only want to allow specific key value pairs in the query string

Example

`google.com/?a=b&c=d` 
should be fine (we want a & c to be allowed as a part of querystring keys)

but

```
google.com/?w=x&y=z
```

should throw an error since we want to throw an error if anything other than a or c is passed as a part of the querystring keys

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: This is a silly requirement as it goes against how the internet generally works.

Comment: I'd be curious for the use-case for this. Do you think this will stop a certain form of attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServletRequest [getParameterNames()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames()) or [getParameterMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()) would give you all of the parameters that were passed in.  So something like this would work:

```
List<String> whiteListedParameters = Arrays.asList("a", "b");

@RequestMapping(value = "google.com", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView render(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();
    while(parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String parameterName = parameterNames.nextElement();
        if(!whiteListedParameters.contains(parameterName)) {
            throw new Exception("Whatever you want");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```